# The list of similar questions is rendered with two different backgrounds

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, blocks

The list of similar questions is rendered using two different backgrounds.

[image: screenshot]

The first one seem the background used with other blocks as well; the other one seems a uniform color background.

This is the same block for this question.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been now fixed. The background of the related questions has been changed, and I don't see anymore two backgrounds being used.

[image: screenshot]